# Replacing the fulcrum lever of a Sturmey-Archer hub with something else.

Tags: internally-geared-hub

I'm trying to find a way to bodge a S.-A. SRF5(W) hub onto a bike with difficult dropouts.  There are two main problems (looking at step 6 of [this diagram](http://www.sjscycles.com/Instructions/Sturmey_Archer/Sturmey_Archer_X_RD5_Hub_Instructions.pdf) and also at [these part pictures p.15,41](http://www.sturmey-archer.com/userfiles/catalogs/Sturmey-Archer-2012-2013-Catalogue-A0-Low-Res.pdf) will aid in understanding this description, should you care to do so):

Problem 1: The axle is a bit too short to take all the washers and nuts on the right-hand (drive) side.

Problem 2: The bend in the fulcrum arm is not sharp enough to get around the lips of the dropouts.

Solution 1: get rid of the fulcrum arm (see link 2, pg. 41) and just use the locating washer (I think I can probably prang it off with a cold-chisel).  I could then cut the fulcrum arm bend off and attach the straight piece with clamps or somesuch to the chainstay.  As I understand it the fulcrum arm is not actually resisting rotational forces (that's done by the anti-rotation washers on the flat-sides axle), but instead is providing a place for the mounting of a barrel-adjuster screw to allow tuning of the shift lever.

Solution 2:  hope that someone is going to tell me that I can simply using Fitting Kit HFIS5.PHSV ([p.15](http://www.sturmey-archer.com/userfiles/catalogs/Sturmey-Archer-2012-2013-Catalogue-A0-Low-Res.pdf) ) which seems to magically replace the fulcrum arm, gear selector guid and g.s.g. protective cover with two simpler parts.

Solution 3:  try to get a thinner, more steep angled fulcrum lever machined for me ... or mock it up out of soft aluminum.  It **LOOKS** as though it's only function is to provide a mounting point for the barrel adjuster screw ([see 3.Gear Adjustment of link 1](http://www.sjscycles.com/Instructions/Sturmey_Archer/Sturmey_Archer_X_RD5_Hub_Instructions.pdf))

Comment: Photos of the actual hub, and the dropout you're trying to work around would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question:

Solution #2 is good.

It's possible to replace the fulcrum arm and pulley assembly with a short guide nut (HMN420) as long as there's a cable stop somewhere on the frame.  You can also buy what S.A. calls "fulcrum clips", see catalogue linked in question above, which effectively provide a cable stop.

This combination has the advantage that it will fit into a tight dropout with deep circular lips that impede the fitting of the fulcrum arm and/or the pulley assembly.

ADDITIONAL INFO: Tony Hadland in his [supplement to The Sturmey Archer Story](http://www.hadland.me.uk/page10.html) mentions that a different, but similar hub, the Sprinter would work with/out the fulcrum arm, so this is a use-case which S.A. has tried to address for some time:

> The Sprinter used the same shell as the 5-StAr; and like the 5-StAr,
>   had the same ratios as the S5 series. However, the Sprinter's
>   arrangements for routing the toggle chain into the hub were novel in
>   that there were four options: the traditional flared wheel nut; or a
>   "gear selector pulley" in a housing which slid over the wheel nut; and
>   in either case with or without an axle-fitting fulcrum lever/clip.
>   These options were felt necessary because of the high cable tension
>   necessary for single cable selection of five gears - which with **an
>   ordinary flared nut and banded-on fulcrum clip could give stiff
>   operation and/or cause the clip to slip along the chainstay. However,
>   with a brazed-on cable stop, the flared nut worked quite well.**

Whether the SRF5(W) has the same concerns about high cable-tension remains to be seen. One [downside to using a fulcrum-clip](http://velo-orange.blogspot.com/2009/07/sa-3-peed-wheels.html?showComment=1246981930470#c6304883918516596817) (e.g. HSJ513 - HSJ514, HSJ548,HSJ543) on three-speed hubs is that the cable can apparently hang loose in certain gears.  A suggested remedy is using full-length cable housing.